# using a join and a where ? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, where-clause

Here's the question I have been given:

> Fetch the delegate no & name along with the module code & name for delegates who have taken a module but have a failing grade.

My tables are, `module`, `delegates`, `session`, `take`, `course`.

**table columns**

```
delegate(name,number) 
Take( grade,number, Course) 
module(code,Name,cost,credits)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT delegate.no,
       delegate.name, 
       module.code,
       module.name AS Course
FROM delegate 
INNER JOIN module,take
WHERE grade  <40;
```

Comment: You should tell more about your table structures.

Comment: Sorry just changed it , im new sorry

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, but beginners always ask this kind of questions.

Comment: you mean the data inside them?

Comment: @user3219120 he meant the fields you have on each table and how they are connect if so

Comment: columns with datatypes ..

Comment: Please state the Column Names under each Table.

Comment: Curious... `INNER JOIN module,take` is actually *valid* SQL. I swear I didn't know before today.

Comment: delegate(name,number)
Take( grade,number, Course)
module( Name,cost,credits)

Thanks

Comment: From his original question I can say that although he is a new user on the website, he respected all of the requirements of asking a question (explain his problem, maybe not in detail but confused people never know what amount of detail is sufficient, show what he tried so far, and asked for help). So I don't think downvoting in such a case is a solution or an encouragement. This 'forum' should be a place for knowledge sharing and explaining, not a place of finger-pointing and getting upvoted answers/comments. We should just answer and explain to him.

Comment: @user3219120 Post your table with column datatype..Our community will help you

Comment: With column datatype? sorry i dont get exactly what you mean, please can you explain :)

Comment: @user3219120, what are the column names under your Tables? :)

Comment: What are the columns in tables `module`, `delegate`, `session`, `take`, `course`?

Comment: delegate(name,number) Take( grade,number, Course) module( Name,cost,credits) Thanks i only need to use these three tables

Comment: sorry add "code" as a  column in module table :)

Comment: Which table contains which delegate is on which module.

Comment: delegate is a table :)

Comment: delegate(DelegateID, DelegateName)

module(ModuleID, ModuleName, Cost, Credits)

take(DelegateID, ModuleID, Grade)

A structure named like that makes it clear that the table 'take' contains which delegate is taking which module.

Comment: sorry , delegate table has number column (student number) and take table has number column also (student number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT delegate.name,
       module.code, 
       module.name,
       delegate.no 
FROM module 
INNER JOIN take 
ON module.code = take.code 
INNER JOIN delegate 
ON delegate.no = take.no 
WHERE grade<40;
```

Comment: It runs with no errors, but only returns the columns with null values?

Comment: When using the INNER JOIN clause, it only returns rows which have corresponding connections between the tables joined. If you have 'chris' under Table delegate and no 'chris' under Table module, then you won't have any result. Make sure you have corresponding values under the Tables you joined :)

Comment: @OP change your columns so you are not doing joins on varchar or nvarchar fields.

Comment: @user3219120, yup, what Martin said is one way to fix your problem, so you'll have simpler SQL statements, but if your problem has to stick with what is given such as the tables and columns, then your only solution is the INNER JOIN.

Comment: Yeah i have been told not to change columns

Comment: Yup, good thing, that way you'll think of new ways to cook the chicken.

Comment: module name is the name of the course e.g web, software 
delegate name is the name of the student e.g. john, shaun

is this why i am getting null values on this part

ON delegate.name=module.name

thanks

Comment: Sorry about that, my bad, I thought they were the common column names under the different tables. It's always not recommended to name the same column names under different tables. If you have 100 Tables, that wud be so hard to track. Is there anything common under module and delegate? ID of the person perhaps?

Comment: If table delegate's number is the person's ID, then module should also have the column number, that's the only way you can join the Tables.

Comment: no there is nothing in common :(

Comment: Then you can't use JOIN. If there is nothing common, it's not possible to solve your problem. Tell the one who made that problem there's something wrong. The you get points for correcting that :))))))

Comment: i fixed it by changing it a little, but thanks for your help chris as your code was 95% of it , here was the working code.

SELECT module.code,
       module.name,
   delegate.name AS Student_Name,
   delegate.no
      
    

FROM module 

INNER JOIN take
ON module.code = take.code

INNER JOIN delegate
ON delegate.no = take.no

WHERE grade<40;

Comment: Happy to help, if my post answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you gave an upvote or mark as answered or both :) Thanks.

Comment: To user3219120 - your original table structure did not have 'code' in the 'take' table. Presumably you have added it?

Comment: i cant upvote as i am not level 15 yet :) but i will come t it when i am :)

Comment: Thanks @user3219120, keep learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT delegate.no,
   delegate.name, 
   module.code,
   module.name
FROM delegate
INNER JOIN module ON delegate.name = module.name
INNER JOIN take ON module.name = take.Course
WHERE take.grade  < 40;
```